# How to disable Facebook Page plugin redirect when logged in

Tags: php, facebook, feed, geoip, facebook-feed

I am putting in a Page Plugin from Facebook on my companies' site. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Our company has different pages for different countries. When we attempt to display the feed of a different country AND the user is logged into facebook, they only see the Country of the page of the person who is logged in. For instance, I set a page to display a Germany Feed. Logged out, I see the German Feed as intended. Logged in, the feed on the page redirects the request to show the US Feed on our page.

I want to FORCE Facebook to show the intended Countries' Feed and NOT have it redirect. (We want our customers to see the other countries feeds intentionally.)

Code as implemented on the page:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=133972420061588";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/convergysGermany" data-width="500" data-height="455" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/convergysGermany">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/convergysGermany">Convergys</a>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possibly but we're tracking this feature request internally.